# Once again about animation (*.ani) cursors from program resources (Delphi 2010)

Tags: delphi

I create a resource file, `Cur.rc`. It contains

```
CUR1   21   "MYCURSOR.ANI"
```

`mycursor.ani` is a file that exists. It's a normal .ani animated cursor.

I compile the resource file using

```
Brcc32 cur.rc
```

which results in the file `cur.res`

In Unit1 of my project (I tried the project's .dpr file as well), I added

```
{$R cur.res}
```

In the FormCreate event,

```
Screen.Cursors[8]:=LoadCursor(HInstance, 'CUR1');
Screen.Cursor := 8;
// p.s. 8 - for an example, can be 0.... n or a constant
```

I run the application. The cursor should change to my animated cursor.

This should be simple. I've tried several different cursor files from different sources. But it doesn't work.

It works if you load from a file:

```
Screen.Cursors [8]:=LoadCursorFromFile('d:\1.ani'); 
Screen.Cursor:=8;
```

How do I load the animated cursor from a resource? Why doesn't it work like loading a normal cursor?

---

This won't work. Apparently, there's no way to load an animated cursor from a resource without going to a file first.

This works, though:

```
// MyCursor.rc
BGCURSOR ANICURSOR "D:\TEMP\Background.ani"

// Unit1.pas
{$R MyCursor.res MyCursor.rc}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Res: TResourceStream;
  FileName: string;
  HC: HCURSOR;
const
  BGCursor = 8;  // Can be anything from 0..32767
begin
  Res := TResourceStream.Create(MainInstance, 'BGCURSOR', 'ANICURSOR');
  try
    FileName := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'BGCursor.ani';
    Res.SaveToFile(FileName);
    HC := LoadCursorFromFile(PChar(FileName));
    Screen.Cursors[BGCursor] := HC;
    Screen.Cursor := BGCursor;
  finally
    DeleteFile(FileName);
    Res.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

I write it after two answers because comments do not wish to be applied.

P.S. Wrote on Delphi 2010, but I think, as on Delphi 7 will go.

The basic question:

Works only for Panel1.
Initial code in the complete set, here text, if to whom long:

The full example has tried to make:

```
1. 3 panels - at form start on everyone are appointed the cursor.
2. Works only on the first or at loading of the cursor from a file
3. All in the complete set (the small program, cursors, etc.) - exe (executed) - too there
```

Initial code in the complete set, here text, if to whom long:

```
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

Const
  CurConst = 8; // 8 .. example, 8 is like me :)
  CurConst1 = 7;
  CurConst2 = 6;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Panel3: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  cur: HCursor;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{$R My.res}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  s: string;
begin
  s:=IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(extractfilepath(paramstr(0)))+'sc1.ani';
  showmessage('Temp value: '+ s);
  Screen.Cursors[CurConst]:=LoadCursorFromFile(pchar(s));
  panel1.Cursor:=CurConst;
  panel2.Cursor:=CurConst;
  panel3.Cursor:=CurConst;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // panel 1
  Screen.Cursors[CurConst] := LoadCursor(HInstance,'V_0');
  panel1.Cursor:=CurConst;
  // panel 2
  Screen.Cursors[CurConst1] := LoadCursor(HInstance,'V_1');
  panel2.Cursor := CurConst1;
  // panel 2
  Screen.Cursors[CurConst2] := LoadCursor(HInstance,'V_2');
  panel3.Cursor := CurConst2;
end;

end.
```

DownLoad (full project code): http://www.sendspace.com/file/jbzrpx (close popup window, look down); mirror: The attention - anything to pay it is not necessary (is downloaded under the slow reference (the size 4 mb)) http://rapidshare.com/files/455515706/TestCursor.zip (no viruses - testing Symantec - 11.6.3000 SEP) In general there an initial code in the complete set - will understand.

Comment: Wow. Invalid ANI file. Weird.  I had the same kind of problem once, and solved it the same way.  But I had this problem with an animated .GIF.

Comment: @Warren - I was surprised to find out more than half of the ani files on my disk were invalid (excluding the ones in the 'Windows' folder). I guess that's why the api tolerates them when loading from a file..

Comment: Yes, you are right, at me bad English - and I see here, that the question has been set correctly, it very much suits me. Many thanks to all who has corrected the text or correctly it has understood.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently the resource loader of the api is somewhat pickier than the file loader, or the requirements are a bit different.

I was able to make your cursors work in the full project code download you provided, without even touching the code, thanks to the executable included:

- Open 'sc1.ani' in a hex editor.

  Locate the second double word in the file (the first is the signature 'RIFF'). The double word is '62 0F 00 00' which is 3938, this is the file size. Modify it to become '5A 0F 00 00', that is '3930', now it denotes the total number of remaining bytes after the length identifier. Save the ani file.

  Open the executable in '[Resource Hacker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/File-Editors/Resource-Hacker.shtml)' or compatible resource editor, and replace 'V_1' with the modified file.

  Save the executable and run.

You can use [Greenfish Icon Editor](http://greenfish.xtreemhost.com/downloads.php) to open your animated cursors and then save again. It seems to produce compatible files.

Comment: +1. Wow - I never would have thought of checking the ANI file bits and bytes. :) That explains why the OP's didn't work and mine did.

Comment: Snx, Greenfish Icon Editor - The program has helped, after reopening (through it) and repeated compilation of a file of resources all cursors have started to be loaded normally. First your way (through hex the editor) too works, but through GIE is easier

Answer (score 1):

Use the deceivingly named [`CreateIconFromResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648060.aspx) API function.

```
var
  res: TCustomMemoryStream;
  cur: HCursor;
begin
  res := TResourceStream.Create(MainInstance, 'BGCURSOR', 'ANICURSOR');
  try
    cur := CreateIconFromResource(res.Memory, res.Size, False, $30000);
    Win32Check(cur <> 0);
    Screen.Cursors[8] := cur;
  finally
    res.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Rob: This doesn't work. It raises an exception: "EOSError: A call to an OS function failed". (I tried this approach too, before I posted my answer.) I used the same resource file contained in my answer, too.

Comment: @Ken, that's odd. This is the same technique used by the other questions here asking about animated cursors in resources. Maybe the "version" parameter is wrong? I have no idea what it means.

Comment: @Rob: That's what I thought when I went down that road. I spent about two hours trying to figure this out, because I couldn't believe that loading from a resource didn't work. I tried a couple of different versions, different values for fIcon, etc., and it wouldn't work.

Comment: mmm......
It is possible an example how you form a file of resources?

BGCURSOR in our case = CUR1?
ANICURSOR - the standard instruction?
Here an example: http://www.sendspace.com/file/gyirsq (1 file, 4 kb, scred.ani)

In my case - writes: the resource is not found (at compilation)

Comment: /\ In a question has published additional data

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Berlin:

To be more specific: If you landed here because you are looking for a way to load animated cursors without first having to save it into a file, this worked for me. The only difference is, move the data to the heap and load it from there.

```
function GetResourceAsAniCursor(const ResName: string; Width, Height: Integer): HCursor;
var
  resInfo: HRSRC;
  resSize: cardinal;
  resHandle: HGLOBAL;
  resData, Data: pchar;
begin
  Result := 0;
  resInfo := FindResource(MainInstance, PWideChar(ResName), PWideChar('ANICURSOR'));
  resHandle := LoadResource(MainInstance, resInfo);
  if resHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    resSize := SizeofResource(MainInstance, resInfo);
    resData := LockResource(resHandle);
    Data := AllocMem(resSize);
    try
      Move(resData^, Data^, resSize);
      Result := CreateIconFromResourceEx(PByte(Data), resSize, False, $00030000, Width, Height, 0);
    finally
      FreeMem(Data);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Usage:

```
const 
 crMyAniCursor = 1;

 Screen.Cursors[crMyAniCursor] := GetResourceAsAniCursor('MYANICURSOR', 128, 128);
```

Comment: @SertacAkyuz could you be please more specific? What is a "broken" cursor?

Comment: Please read the question, then I won't have to be more specific. I wonder how can you post an answer without reading the question. Also read the accepted answer, it will give you a hint of the actual issue and explain what is broken.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Maybe you should read the question, try to concentrate on the sentences ending with question mark. Also, read the statements where OP and some others states that animated cursors can't be loaded from resource, only from file. The fact, that his cursor was broken has nothing to do with his question. Either change the question to: How can I load a broken cursor or delete the thread. Then this is the first google hit for Delphi how to load an animated cursor from resource.

Comment: So you think that the accepted answer is a lie. And the OP accepted it without even trying it. And the OP lies in his comment to the accepted answer. Good thing that you are not fooled with all these lies. Go on...

Comment: I don't know where your problem is. I wanted to help others but all I get is hate. I'll contact SO to find a resolution on this and make a complaint against you because I don't think that this kind of attitude fits for SO.

Comment: Help here is answering the question. And what you regard as hate is my trying to explain the problem.

Comment: I have answered the question. Actually my answer is the one and only right answer here for this question, and your answer should be denied and downvoted. Those .ani files are not corrupted, they were just read in the wrong way so your hex-hack was superfluous and wrong. And yet, you try to lecture me for reading the question meanwhile you didn't even try my solution. I've the feeling that you are just trolling here around. Please leave me alone and do not ever reply on my activity on SO.

Comment: Thanks, you've finally answered to my first comment. I suggest you to read the RIFF specification, those files are corrupted. In any case if your code load those corrupted cursors it answers the question alright.

Comment: That was an unexpected twist. Yes it does, the winapi reads it's own "corrupted" format. Who would have thought that. I'm glad we sorted this out in just 10 comments..

Comment: I tested this. Although I don't understand what makes it so, it does seem to be working. I replaced `PWideChar('ANICURSOR')` with `RT_ANICURSOR` to be able to work with the original project but I think those links should be dead by now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. Apparently, there's no way to load an animated cursor from a resource without going to a file first.

This works, though:

```
// MyCursor.rc
BGCURSOR ANICURSOR "D:\TEMP\Background.ani"

// Unit1.pas
{$R MyCursor.res MyCursor.rc}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Res: TResourceStream;
  FileName: string;
  HC: HCURSOR;
const
  BGCursor = 8;  // Can be anything from 0..32767
begin
  Res := TResourceStream.Create(MainInstance, 'BGCURSOR', 'ANICURSOR');
  try
    FileName := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'BGCursor.ani';
    Res.SaveToFile(FileName);
    HC := LoadCursorFromFile(PChar(FileName));
    Screen.Cursors[BGCursor] := HC;
    Screen.Cursor := BGCursor;
  finally
    DeleteFile(FileName);
    Res.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Of course user may need administrator privileges to succeed on UAC enabled computers.  Why not use a temporary file? or a file in a user writable directory?

Comment: @jachguate: Write it wherever you need to - my example was to show how, which was the question. I could just as well have said "Of course, you need a computer to do this. You'll also need a copy of Delphi, and a keyboard." Why complicate the answer with unecessary code, when it wasn't the question? - OK. I'll fix it for you.

Comment: Wow! 
{$R MyCursor.res MyCursor.rc}
- For question editing - separate thanks.
-------------------------------
So unless it is possible? Probably while Delphi badly I know...

In the evening I will check up, now there is nothing to execute.
I think, that the difference in a time zone a little to us stirs. It is necessary to have a sleep a little... (unreal work this forum with IE 9.. .) Anyhow - already I see other decisions (and in the answer more low, too thanks) than in native inquiry Codegear (ebarcadero) Delphi,
Which why that in more in answers - is ground under C ++ :(

Comment: ок, the dream was gone. 
Is not present - does not interest from a file: it works always, wrote about it, probably or the editor has not up to the end corrected difficulties of transfer.
And resource record on a disk with loading after the cursor - too does not interest By the way, I think that in this case the cursor to keep as RcData better.

Comment: Excuse, but in the comment it not gjvtoftncz (and answering more low too this text) test of the project, cursors and a question - why one works and another is not present? look UP