# Animated Cursor Playing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a Form "TForm1" having one "TAnimate1". I have one AVI Resource as File Name "Animate 01.avi" with Resource Identifier "AVI" and one "Animated Cursor" as File Name "Cursor 01.ani" with Resource Identifier "8".I wish to play "Animate 01.avi" on "FormCreate" event and set default cursor as "8". I'm using "Delphi XE2".

Please download my project file from "http://hotfile.com/dl/137675080/34f701f/KoushikHalder01.7z.html" and tell where to rectify.

Comment: Better include the relevant code parts in the question. Also, you've both given file names and resource ids, are you loading from files or resources? Also, you're not mixing resource 'identifier' and 'type', right? An animate control loads an avi from an AVI resource, yours have an AVI identifier (perhaps also the type?).

Comment: As per my knowledge I have done everything except some small errors. Please download and check and also tell me where to recify. Please.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, downloaded...

First, you're putting the avi in an 'RCDATA' section. As I've already said, that won't work. An animate control loads the avi file of an AVI type. So this line

```
AVI RCDATA "KoushikHalder.avi"
```

in your '.rc' file, should be in fact:

```
AVI AVI "KoushikHalder.avi"
```

You can put whatever you like for ID, but the resource type should be **AVI**.

Second, you would load the avi by its *resource identifier*. You've given an 'AVI' identifier for it. So this line in your code:

```
Animate01.ResName :='KoushikHalder.avi';
```

should in fact be:

```
Animate01.ResName :='AVI';
```

Third, your '.ani' file does not conform with the standards. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5519480/243614) for details. You won't be able to load that ani file unless you correct it.

Fourth, you're not loading the ani file correctly. It's identifier is not '8', it's 8. So the below line:

```
Screen.Cursors[8] := LoadCursor(HInstance, '8');
```

Should be

```
Screen.Cursors[8] := LoadCursor(HInstance, MakeIntResource(8));
```

(or Pointer(8)..).

Lastly, you have to set the cursor somewhere to your ani file so that you can see it. For instance:

```
Screen.Cursor := 8;
```

or

```
BitBtn01.Cursor := 8;
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now avi resource is playing but the problem for ANI cursor is still there. I have done everything according to you comment. But you have told "'ani' file does not conform with the standards", please tell me those standards. I dont want to play ANI cursor from any file. I need to play from resource only.

Comment: @Koushik - Read the accepted answer to the linked question. It explains why the 'ani' file is *bad* and gives two different methods to make the 'ani' behave. After you have a good 'ani', include that one in your resource file and *build* your application.